# Mysql gem with MAMP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm running MAMP for local development on Snow Leopard (64bit obviously).
I'm trying to run a rake task for a ruby on rails application and get the following error:

"
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql
"

I do however have my msql gem installed:

When I run "gem list"

It lists: 
- mysql (2.8.1)

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:
I'm new to Ruby (and Rails) so not sure if this is all the required information to solve this problem. Please let me know if additional info is needed.

EDIT2:
I tried running this command:
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/Mamp/Library/bin/mysql_config

Which gave the following result:

**Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed**
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result
No definition for field_name
No definition for field_table
No definition for field_def
No definition for field_type
No definition for field_length
No definition for field_max_length
No definition for field_flags
No definition for field_decimals
No definition for time_inspect
No definition for time_to_s
No definition for time_get_year
No definition for time_get_month
No definition for time_get_day
No definition for time_get_hour
No definition for time_get_minute
No definition for time_get_second
No definition for time_get_neg
No definition for time_get_second_part
No definition for time_set_year
No definition for time_set_month
No definition for time_set_day
No definition for time_set_hour
No definition for time_set_minute
No definition for time_set_second
No definition for time_set_neg
No definition for time_set_second_part
No definition for time_equal
No definition for error_errno
No definition for error_sqlstate

Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result
No definition for field_name
No definition for field_table
No definition for field_def
No definition for field_type
No definition for field_length
No definition for field_max_lengt
No definition for field_flags
No definition for field_decimals
No definition for time_inspect
No definition for time_to_s
No definition for time_get_year
No definition for time_get_month
No definition for time_get_day
No definition for time_get_hour
No definition for time_get_minute
No definition for time_get_second
No definition for time_get_neg
No definition for time_get_second_part
No definition for time_set_year
No definition for time_set_month
No definition for time_set_day
No definition for time_set_hour
No definition for time_set_minute
No definition for time_set_second
No definition for time_set_neg
No definition for time_set_second_part
No definition for time_equal
No definition for error_errno
No definition for error_sqlstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had an error in my gem file (mysql was commented out) I feel like an idiot but at least it was solved. (thx to Philip Arndt http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/141d92ff1fa0ad18 )

Comment: Hi I am totally new to rubygem, where can I find the gem file? I am getting the same error.

Comment: In the route of your Rails directory there is a file called "Gemfile"